# Configure aws auth on hashicorp vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to configure aws auth on hashicorp vault. Below is the step that I did. But I am not sure if I have done it correctly. Although it works.

1. Create IAM user with the below policy

```
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create IAM role with the below policy

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-example-role"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Enable AWS Auth on Vault

```
export VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200

export VAULT_NAMESPACE=namespace_main/namespace_tenant_1

vault auth enable -path=aws aws  

vault write auth/aws/config/client secret_key=xxx access_key=xxx region=us-east-1

vault write auth/aws/role/dev-role auth_type=iam bound_iam_principal_arn="arn:aws:iam::1234xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-example-role" policies=namespace_tenant_1_admin max_ttl=50h 

vault login -method=aws -path=aws role=dev-role
```

Questions:

1. Does that means I am using a role to login to vault?
2. What is the difference between the 2 `vault write` above? Do I need both or only one.

Comment: Have you referenced the doc for AWS auth: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/aws?

Comment: @Matt Schuchard Yes i did. But still a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that means I am using a role to login to vault?

Yes, in this method the credentials are not stored in vault but they are being generated on demand. That's why we associate a role and policy, so that the credentials are generated on demand depending upon the configuration we have done.

> vault write auth/aws/config/client secret_key=xxx access_key=xxx region=us-east-1

This vault write is writing the AWS account details on the location `auth/aws/config/` and with the secret key and access key you provide the credentials of the AWS account.

while this vault write auth/aws/role/dev-role auth_type=iam bound_iam_principal_arn="arn:aws:iam::1234xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-example-role" policies=namespace_tenant_1_admin max_ttl=50h

is associating a permissions a particular resource has to generate the credentials . and yes you can refer the documentation for more information.